# C++: WHILE loop after timed callback blocks the callback?

Tags: c++, loops, boost, timer, boost-asio

I am using the from boost suggested solution for a timed callback which can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html). I am using it to run the timed callback in parallel to other methods. But when I am executing a loop after setting the callback, the callback stops:

```
//this is the main cpp file

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        t.async_wait(print);
        io.run();

        ....some part later I then call a function with while(){} loop inside....
        eng.Loopfunction();
```

After Loopfunction() is called, the timed callback doesn't work anymore. Do you know how to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the timed callback doesn't work anymore

Is it called only once?

According to the code:

1. `io.run()` blocks the main thread
2. `print` is called once
3. `io.run()` unblocks the main thread
4. `eng.Loopfunction` is called

That how it must work. Note that `deadline_timer` is called only once. If you want timer to be called each second, you need to call `deadline_timer::async_wait` at the end of `print` like that:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
deadline_timer t(io);

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

  // call this function again in 1 second
  t.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds(1) );
  t.async_wait(print);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    t.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds(1) );
    t.async_wait(print);
    io.run();
```

Comment: @user2212461, `io.run()` blocks main thread while it has a work. See my example, there `io.run()` blocks for ever, because we add new work to `boost::asio::io_service` at the end of `print`.

If you want `eng.Loopfunction()` to work in parallel - you need to create another thread and call `io.run()` from it.

Comment: This prints "Hello world" faster than 1 second (seems like it creates always a new thread??) and blocks the code below io.run(). Where is the error?

Comment: still the same behavior

Comment: @user2212461 Sorry, I'm away from boost now. See my updated code.